# UICollectionview scroll hangs while inserting new data and random crash on load more

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add new items to `UICollectonView` by `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` but i get random crash on this in abpve scenario

1. If any user interaction is performed
2. while insertion

`Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (22) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (10 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

Also the UICollectionview` scroll get hangs while i am inserting , Anyone plz suggest some solution.Thanks

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items

    print("section called")
    if(activityTableView.onlineFeedsData.length != 0){
        if(customSC.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
            activityTableView.selectedType = "latest"
            return activityTableView.postArr.count
        }else{
            activityTableView.selectedType = "popular"
            return activityTableView.postPopularArr.count
        }


    }


    return 0


}
```

**Insert Function**

```
func insertFeeds(data : NSData , type : String){
  activityTableView.performBatchUpdates({

                        print("closure")

                        self.activityTableView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
                        self.activityTableView.postArr.addObjectsFromArray(resultArr as [AnyObject])
                        self.activityTableView.onlineFeedsData = NSData(data: try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.activityTableView.postArr, options: [])).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableData // new

                        print("closure end")

                        }, completion: { (bool) in

                            print("completion")
                    })

 }
```